# Alias attribute in a django template

Tags: django, templates, variables, alias

Could we make an alias on an attribute in a django template? I think this is not work, but I tried  `{% loan.customer as customer %}`.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you've tagged this with the wrong language.

Comment: @guest yes, you are right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want the **with** template tag.

```
{% with loan.customer as customer %}     
    <div>{{customer}}</div>
{% endwith %}
```

**this is old style** but still supported see the 
[django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#with) for new style and more info.

For now, **New style**

```
{% with customer=loan.customer %}
```

Comment: Could you tell me what I have to do if I want to to such thing for many aliases; for instance, `{% loan.customer as customer %}` and `{%  request.user as user%}`?

Comment: Actually nested **with** is not supported by django template I think

Comment: remember @J.Doe this is old style which is still being supported. I gave this answer coz your question was in that format. For now and new style it would be {% with customer=loan.customer  %}